# XLSX file created on linux has different name when sending it to windows

Tags: python, datetime, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I can't specify in which moment something goes wrong.

On linux via script im creating xlsx file using xlsxwriter. The thing is on linux created files have correct name, then when i open them on windows (thanks to network location) they have totally different names.

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# *-* coding: utf-8 *-*

import xlsxwriter
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass


class Excel:
    def __init__(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        datetoday = now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S")
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('GMDC_' + datetoday + '.xlsx')
        workbook.close()
```

Example created file by this

GMDC_03.09.2019-16:41:00.xlsx

GMDC_05.09.2019-08:42:03.xlsx

The same files but visible on windows

GMDC_0~1

GMDC_0~2

Is there something wrong with encoding or the datetime format which could be the issue?

Comment: This is a limitation of the old FAT fileystem, see [Wikipedia/filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename#VFAT_and_Computer-generated_8.3_filenames). Can you elaborate more on your setup? What Windows version, what filesystems are you using etc.?

Comment: Windows 10 enterprise, regarding filesystems its NTFS. On linux, its NFS